# js2coffee: command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript

Under Ubuntu 10, I installed using: `npm install js2coffee`

Seems to install smoothly

I enter `npm ls`

Returns:

```
/root
----js2coffee@0.1.3
--------coffee-script@1.3.3
--------underscore@1.3.3
```

I try executing `js2coffee mywebapp.js` but get `js2coffee: command not found`

What's wrong? What else is needed to get js2coffee working properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install by `sudo npm install js2coffee -g` it will create the executable then.

Comment: +1. You might not need `sudo`; it depends on where npm is installing things. The active ingredient here is `-g`, for "global." You may also need to add npm's global install dir to your `PATH`.